# How to use UISearchController for searching Mandarin language?

Tags: swift, uisearchcontroller

I try to make a travel data with json & add `UISearchController`.
It looks like I can run `UISearchController` with English and number; however, cannot search Mandarin when I type keyword.

Here is code, will appreciate anyone who can help me!

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        let searchString = searchController.searchBar.text!
        filteredData = travelData.filter({ (data) -> Bool in
            return (data.Name.contains(searchString) && data.Add.contains(searchString))
        })
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    var travelData = [DetailData]()
    var filteredData = [DetailData]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        guard let url = "http://data.ntpc.gov.tw/api/v1/rest/datastore/382000000A-002491-001".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed), let downloadUrl = URL(string: url) else {return}
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadUrl) { (data, response, error) in
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            print("Decoder")
            if let data = data{
                do{
                    let json = try decoder.decode(Alldata.self, from: data)
                    self.travelData = json.result.records
                    print("json")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }catch{
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()

        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        definesPresentationContext = true
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false

        let image = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = image
    }
}
```

Attached with gif link to better understand my situation.
[image]

Comment: _"cannot search Mandarin when I type keyword."_. What happens? Error message? Wrong result? No result? Please give more details.

Comment: @AshleyMills It can run without any error message. When I type number, it will search as usual. But when I type Mandarin, it does not search the word.

Comment: Does **Mandarin** exist in your json? Did you check?

Comment: @TheTiger Yes, I paste part of json for your reference.

Comment: {
Id: "C3_382000000A_206337",
Name: "正傳統小吃店",
Description: "外觀古色古香的正傳統擔仔麵，標榜著「臺灣味、人情味、古早味」，不管是臺灣小吃、海鮮、山產野味、食療藥膳、擔仔麵，或是日式冷食，本店都可品嘗的到。源源不絕的顧客在店中漫談著，加上個性開朗的老闆和老闆娘熱情的招呼聲和笑容，輕易地就勾起臺灣人與人之間最珍貴的感覺呢！本店的擔仔麵是十分有特色！老闆用心地用魚骨、雞骨熬製高湯，加上柴魚片和蔬菜，絲毫不會有腥味，肉燥口味偏鹹，和臺南偏甜的口味不同。",
Tel: "886-2-22199753",
Add: "新北市新店區建國路209號1樓",
Zipcode: "231",
Opentime: "下午17:30~零晨2:00 (除夕~初二其他時間均無休)&#xd;&#xa;",
Map: "",
Px: "121.53762",
Py: "24.98031",
Class: "6",
Website: "",
Parkinginfo: "",
Changetime: "2018/06/20 09:56:25"
},

Comment: Lol even I can not see **Mandarin** in this json too.

Comment: Just think once me and your `textField` know `English` language but the data is in different language. So how will me and `textField` understand what is it.

Comment: Can you find **Mandrain** in this line **क्या तुम इस पंक्ति में मंडारिन ढून्ढ सकते हो?** and Yes this line contains the **Mandrain** for sure.

Comment: @TheTiger Really? How about the API with this: http://data.ntpc.gov.tw/api/v1/rest/datastore/382000000A-002491-001   Guess data could not figure what language it is, but there should be way to fix it.

Comment: @KDerek You are working on filtering not translating. These are two different things. You need to enter the keywords in same language as your json is. Remember code compares it as `string/text/number` it doesn't matter what language it is. `a==a = true`, `一个==一个 = true` but `a==一个 = false.`

Comment: @TheTiger And the line you add "क्या तुम इस पंक्ति में मंडारिन ढून्ढ सकते हो?" is garbled to me.

Comment: @KDerek You are working on filtering not translating. These are two different things. – TheTiger           What should I write to filter with translating?

Comment: @KDerek You are working on filtering not translating. These are two different things. You need to enter the keywords in same language as your json is. Remember code compares it as string/text/number it doesn't matter what language it is. a==a = true, 一个==一个 = true but a==一个 = false. – TheTiger                  Thank you! I will try to run on my phone again and check with text

Comment: After running again on my phone, weird thing happen. I type unrelated word and it still search out some item. (e.g., type "九" on search bar, and result shows "金山"). In Mandrain they are totally different word.

Comment: Could you please update your question with this example? Same language character and result. It will make more sense to answer.

Comment: @TheTiger Is it garbled to you? It is like when I type 一个, it shows 二个...

Comment: @TheTiger I updated question with gif link.

Comment: Should not be `(data.Name.contains(searchString) && data.Add.contains(searchString))` is `(data.Name.contains(searchString) || data.Add.contains(searchString))` means if `Add` or `Name` contains the searched string it should show you? `&&` means searched text should be in both `Add` and `Name`.

Comment: @TheTiger Even though I deleted && data.Add.contains(searchString), only show (data.Name.contains(searchString), still happen like gif link.

Comment: I don't know Chinese language but in terms of programming `"ABC.contains("a")` will be true or you need a `case sensitive` comparison.

Comment: How to use case sensitive for comparison? Thanks for help!